# How to copy files from private Github to Webhosting?

Tags: git, symfony, ssh, versioning, web-hosting

I'm currently developing a new website with Symfony2. I'm using Github for Version Control. My webhosting is ssh able and I'm using putty to access it.

As far as I know it should be possible to synchronize the latest commit (master) to the webhosting via ssh? (Means after a commit I would like to synchronize the website data to the webhosting to make it public)

I looked up the rsync commend but I don't really find a solution. I tried the following command:

```
rsync git@github.com:namexy/namexy.git /
```

Even dough I think I have the SSH Key installed, I got the following error message:

```
/home/namexy/.ssh/config: line 1: Bad configuration option: sh-rsa
/home/namexy/.ssh/config: terminating, 1 bad configuration options
rsync: connection unexpectedly closed (0 bytes received so far) [Receiver]
rsync error: unexplained error (code 255) at io.c(601) [Receiver=3.0.8]
```

Is this a problem because of the command or some error in the ssh key?

Thanks in advance for your help guys!

Comment: Take a look at capifony

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an error in your ssh-config file. The error message is pretty clear about this:

```
/home/namexy/.ssh/config: line 1: Bad configuration option: sh-rsa
/home/namexy/.ssh/config: terminating, 1 bad configuration options
```

You have included an option named **sh-rsa** that doesn't exist.

It looks like you copied your ssh-pulic key to `~/.ssh/config` instead of `~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub`!

A ssh **public-key** (rsa) looks somewhat like this ...

```
ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAADAQABAAABAQDD3+wBomfzBwA8IXw4x/Ud3kt5541rOw4UVXuJaQbMYXA5lq686AyEbtk3L
...
mNVHcR2J user@host
```

... while your `~/.ssh/config` should be something like this:

```
Host github.com github gh
  Hostname github.com
  User git
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

Comment: I got a bit further and have now the following message: